# Classic ASP INSERT INTO with quotes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, asp-classic

I'd like to add quotes to a record when it's entered into the SQL DB, for example:

User inputs: 1234

In the database it is recorded as "1234"

I'm using a Classic ASP form to do this - is this something I should do in the code before the Insert query or would I be better suited adding in the quotes back-end with SQL?

Thanks

Comment: I think I've found the answer, by using QUOTENAME function in SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use query parameters.  Escaping apostrophes is one of the good things they will do for you.

Comment: Could you provide the link of a tutorial/example? All query parameters I've found are `Select` queries. I'm looking for an `Insert`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use query parameters as Dan suggested, or if you are writing raw SQL you can [use double quotes](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?404890-How-to-handle-quotes-in-database-insert) to enter a single quote